# How to reuse a Custom Material-ui button inside a react-app?

Tags: reactjs, button, components, material-ui, reusability

I'm developing my first React app. I've imported a Material-ui button and I've customized it.

Now I want to reuse this custom button in several components of my app. I want a different text for each time I use this custom button.

Where do I need to write this specific text for each button?

My button is visible when I import it in other components, but I can't see the text I wrote inside the button component. The button stays empty.

My custom button component : MyButton:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = () => ({
  button: {
    margin: 50,
    padding: 10,
    width: 180,
    fontSize: 20
  }
});

function MyButton(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
      <b>  </b>
    </Button>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyButton);
```

The other component where I import MyButton component : Home :

```
import React from "react";
import "../App.css";
import MyButton from "./Button";

function Header() {
  return (
    <header className="Header">
      {/* background image in css file */}
      <h1>Welcome </h1>
      <h3> description...</h3>
      <MyButton>Play now</MyButton>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

I expect the button to show "Play now" ([expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEJmN.png)) but for now it stays empty ([actual output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql08I.png)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also, I've found another solution that offers the possibility to write directly the text inside each button (children of MyButton), and customize it if needed.

Pass "children" keyword as "props" to MyButton component :

```
function MyButton(props) {
  const { classes, children } = props;
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
      <b>{children}</b>
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Then write the text of your button inside the button as you will do in html :

```
<MyButton> Play now </MyButton>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get the most flexibility from your custom `Button` if you pass all of the props along to the wrapped `Button`. This will automatically take care of `children` and `classes` so long as you use class keys in your `styles` object that match the [CSS classes](https://material-ui.com/api/button/#css) supported for the wrapped component.

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = () => ({
  root: {
    margin: 50,
    padding: 10,
    width: 180,
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});

function CustomButton(props) {
  return <Button variant="contained" color="primary" {...props} />;
}

export default withStyles(styles)(CustomButton);
```

[image: Edit Custom Button]

Notice in the sandbox example, that this allows you to still leverage other `Button` features like `disabled`, specify additional styles, or override some properties specified in `CustomButton`.

If you have a scenario where you need to handle `children` explicitly (in my example above I used `fontWeight` CSS instead of the `<b>` tag), you can use the following syntax to still pass all the props through to the wrapped component:

```
function CustomButton({children, ...other}) {
  return <Button variant="contained" color="primary" {...other}><b>{children}</b></Button>;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass text of button as props to your button component

```
<MyButton text="Play now"></MyButton>
```

Then inside MyButton component you can get it like

```
  function MyButton(props) {
   const { classes,text } = props;
    return (
     <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button}>
       <b> {text} </b>
      </Button>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear solution, it's working now. 

Also, I've found another solution with "children" keyword passed as "props" to my button component. This way I can directly write the text inside the button, and customize it if needed.

Comment: Your welcome . Yes that is another way to do with children prop .